# AWS Cloud front over global accelerator - Is it caching and Lambda@edge?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-global-accelerator

Global accelerator looks like the obvious choice over cloud front. Except for usecases which need caching or Lambda at Edge.
Are there some other usecase too where cloud front has an advantage over Global accelerator ?
thanks.

Comment: "' obvious choice " for what? They server different purpose.

Comment: @Marcin,  obvious choice to decrease latency. So any usecases where one should consider could front if dymanic data and no processing at edge is needed ?

Answer (score 1):

*"Global Accelerator is a good fit for non-HTTP use cases, such as gaming (UDP), IoT (MQTT), or Voice over IP, as well as for **HTTP use cases that specifically require static IP addresses or deterministic, fast regional failover.**"* ~ https://aws.amazon.com/global-accelerator/faqs/

Comment: Yes, thats also what I meant, Global accelerator is the better choice, except caching and lamda. Any other usecases where cloud front has an edge ?

Comment: CloudFront has TLS termination so HTTPS requests have lower latency.